# Accelerated Mobile Pages for User Created Project (Pages)

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I understand that AMP is primarily used to display (mostly) static content faster than if it were not AMP pages.

I also understand that only certain pages on a website can be AMP pages while others are non-AMP pages.

What I'm unsure is what happens when the page that I want to `AMP` are pages that users create? For instance, if user X were to create a project and publish that project and in return got a URL like `www.myapp.com/PROJECT_ID` and the url changes for every single project created on the site, how can I leverage the advantages of AMP so that all the projects that any user creates on the site gets the benefits of AMP?

I've read all the pages on the docs, searched Stack Overflow and Google for relevant blog posts, but that have been futile thus far.

Comment: Can you try [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=OO9oKhs80aI) on this AMP Channel?

Comment: @noogui I've seen most of the videos on YouTube and both the tutorials on the docs page. I have all the AMP restrictions passing (there are no validation errors) but I'm not sure how user-created-pages (myapp.com/PROJECT_ID) could leverage the benefits of AMP as the url changes every time a user creates a project and I want ALL of the pages to leverage AMP

Comment: Since AMP is just regular HTML, I don't understand what the issue you're facing is? As long as all your user-created pages are valid AMP, there's no additional action you need to take.